# Using omniauth-linkedin for educations, skills, connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm using omniauth-linkedin gem in Rails and trying to get data from 'r_fullprofile' and 'r_network'.

In omniauth.rb:

```
  provider :linkedin, 'consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 
       :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network', 
       :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", 
                   "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", 
                   "location", "connections", "skills", "date-of-birth", "phone-numbers",        
                   "educations", "three-current-positions" ]
```

In controller:

```
render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

The resultant output seems only to have data for 'r_basicprofile'. How can I obtain for parsing the rest of the desired data (e.g. "connections", "skills", "educations")?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with using Omniauth from Devise.

I had to make a change to put the :fields => [...] in to curly braces.

In your case:

```
  provider :linkedin, 'consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 
       {:scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network', 
       :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", 
                   "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", 
                   "location", "connections", "skills", "date-of-birth", "phone-numbers",        
                   "educations", "three-current-positions" ]}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference at all - does this actually work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you but now some fields have a different name. I put this on my devise.rb and it works:

```
config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['OAUTH_LINKEDIN_ID'], ENV['OAUTH_LINKEDIN_SECRET'],
fields: %w(id email-address first-name last-name headline industry picture-url public-profile-url location num-connections), image_size: {height: 1600}
```

`connections` is now `num-connections`, see [Linkedin Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Comment: can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849520/how-to-fetch-linkedin-user-data